# Can the verb "include" be followed by a clause?

Tags: clauses

Is this structure correct?

> We guarantee to everyone high-standard care, which **includes**,
>   for example, our client centre **is** open for you even of weekends and technical support **is** available non-stop.

Comment: 'We guarantee to everyone high-standard care, which includes, for example, that our client centre is open for you ...' is a structure often seen on the internet.

Comment: It is also idiomatic to say "which *means*, for example, that our ...."

Comment: What the OP seems to mean to say is "... which includes ... **the fact that** our client centre is open ..." -- the verb *include* forward references the noun *the fact*.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'includes' needs some sort of noun, not a clause, so if each *is* was replaced by *being*, it would make sense.

Comment: Please use the comment option where appropriate.

Comment: Perfect answer, but GR.

Comment: @Kris, one year on, I still get confused about the appropriate use of answer and comment.  Could you please explain your previous comments.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: David, 1. "I think ..." is an opinion/ comment. 2. Answers better be supported and referenced. See also:  http://english.stackexchange.com/help   HTH.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidGarner noted, using "being" in place of "is" would solve the problem. This is because "include" should be followed by a noun, and if it is a clause it should be one that at least acts like a noun. "Being" is the gerund of the verb "to be", and gerunds act like nouns, e.g. "Nagging doesn't help the situation." where "nagging" is the subject(and hence a noun) denoting an action. With "being", your sentence would look like: 
... which includes, for example, our client centre **being** open for you even on weekends and technical support **being** available non-stop.

You can also try replacing the clauses with real nouns complemented by modifiers:
... which includes, for example, **client services on weekends** and **technical support of constant availability**.
(or you could use "constantly available technical support", even "24/7 technical support" if that fits your situation)